# Wrong table height

Tags: html, css

Why do I get wrong table total height in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/nfb82/

I specified height and width for each cell. In total I need to get 160x90 table dimensions. Width is calculated correctly while I get wrong height. Moreover, in my site I get 97px, in jsfiddle example I have 101px. 
I thought about borders which may be taken into account, but why then I get right width. Also I tried to change height (decreased each cell height by 1px) but in any case I got wrong height

Html:

```
<div class="template-markup _16x9" data-template-id="2">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" style="width: 128px; height: 72px;">1</td>
                <td style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 32px; height: 40px;">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 18px; width: 160px;">4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="resolution">1920x1080</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.template-markup {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
    .template-markup table {
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
        .template-markup table tr td {
            border: 1px solid #333;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
        }
        .template-markup table tr td:hover {
            background-color: #DDD;
        }   
        .template-markup table tr td.selected {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    .template-markup .resolution {
        text-align: center;
        clear: both;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .template-markup._16x9 {
        width: 160px;
    }
        .template-markup._16x9 table {
            width: 160px; 
            height: 90px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine in it is because padding and border values are also being set on the table elements

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp